# JSON output using python including unwanted symbols

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

I am using Python for the first time to create a simple JSON parser. However, when printing the JSON data to the console, it includes many extra brackets and other symbols that are unwanted. I am also running Python 2.7.10.

```
import json
from urllib2 import urlopen

response = urlopen("https://finance.yahoo.com/webservice/v1/symbols/allcurrencies/quote?format=json")
source = response.read()

# print(source)

data = json.loads(source)

# print(json.dumps(data, indent=2))

usd_rates = dict()

for item in data['list']['resources']:
    name = item['resource']['fields']['name']
    price = item['resource']['fields']['price']
    usd_rates[name] = price
    print(name, price)
```

And the output is as follows:

[image]

When I try to change the python version to 3.7.10:

[image]

Comment: "I am also running Python 3.7." - your output shows you're definitely not.

Comment: @user2357112 you're right. Somehow the version reverted back to 2.7.10 even though I just updated it. Do you think that is what is affecting the output?

Comment: On Python 2, that `print` syntax is going to print tuples instead of considering `name` and `price` as separate arguments.

Comment: use "{} {}".format(name, price) instead of print(name, price)

Comment: `print name, price` will also work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are actually printing a tuple with python 2 `print` syntax and the `u` character is a unicode flag ([What exactly do "u" and "r" string flags do, and what are raw string literals?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081640/what-exactly-do-u-and-r-string-flags-do-and-what-are-raw-string-literals)).

Also in python 3 you couldn't use `urllib2` but would have to use `urllib.request`.

This code works for me (python 3.6.5):

```
import json
from urllib.request import urlopen

response = urlopen("https://finance.yahoo.com/webservice/v1/symbols/allcurrencies/quote?format=json")
source = response.read()


data = json.loads(source)

usd_rates = dict()

for item in data['list']['resources']:
    name = item['resource']['fields']['name']
    price = item['resource']['fields']['price']
    usd_rates[name] = price
    print(name, price)
```

EDIT ---------

From the image you posted it looks like you have python 3 installed but your `usr/bin/python` is a symbolic link to `usr/bin/python2`.

If you want to run python 3 by default you could create an alias.
Check this link for more info https://askubuntu.com/questions/320996/how-to-make-python-program-command-execute-python-3
(should be valid info for macs too)

Comment: See the image above for what happens when I try to change the python version

Comment: From the image you posted it looks to me that you have opened the python3 console. If you want to run a script from shell you could type something like `python3 script.py`

Answer (score -2):

Convert name and price to string

`print(str(name), str(price))`

or
use

`name = str(item['resource']['fields']['name'])`